# How to have a figure with panels composed of plots from a data frame (python 2.7)?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Say I have two plots

```
panel1 = df1.plot(kind='bar')

plt.close()

panel2 = df2.plot(kind='bar')

plt.close()
```

Where df1 and df2 are data frames with the data I want to plot. I want to have a figure with panel1 and panel2 as its constituent axes. I have tried indexing the axes and adding them as subplots, but I can't figure out how to have a 1x2 figure with them as panels *without* having to extract the data from each data frame to plot normally. I will repeat the operation with several figures and data frames, and since they already contain labelling and other useful information, I want to do it this way. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.plot` has an `ax` parameter:

> ax : matplotlib axes object, default None

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))

pl.figure()
ax=pl.subplot(121)
df1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)

ax=pl.subplot(122)
df2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: The argument ax=ax was the key. Very useful.